# Store data on a web page without a database using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment in which I need to use just html and javascript to store some records (let's just say a name and a phone number), that can be deleted/updated later. The catch is I can not use a database of any kind.

For simplicity sake, let's just say I just have a webpage that has 2 fields and 1 button: a name field, a phone number field, and a submit button.  When the user presses submit, the information needs to be stored.

In my experience with Java, I would do something like this: get user input, save data to a .txt file. So I thought perhaps I can do something similar, however, in my search so far the responses I see make me believe that there is no way to create a .txt (or any type of) file using javasript/html.

So my question is just this: how can I save data using just html/javascript? Or is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously? Who downvotes this within 17 seconds of it being posted? There's no way it was even read in that time...

Comment: you can use a .json file to store data in Json format.

Comment: JSP has the Server context for non db persistant storage accross sessions. though this assigment is probably about cookies or localstorage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp

You can use web storage.

From W3Schools:

> With web storage, web applications can store data locally within the
>   user's browser.
>
> Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included
>   in every server request. Web storage is more secure, and large amounts
>   of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.
>
> Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and
>   information is never transferred to the server.
>
> Web storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from
>   one origin, can store and access the same data.

Comment: @Alberto, not really, because the call must take the `http` and not `file`. so the example at w3schools works, but not locally.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

1. The simplest way is HTML5 local storage. This is quite basic and allows you to set a name and value for each record. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.
2. You can use either IndexedDB (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or Web SQL (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm). Both of these are pretty similar in the sense that they both essentially create an offline database. However, some browsers support one and some support the other so it can be difficult to implement.
3. My personal favourite solution is YDN-DB (http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/index.html). It is a JavaScript library that uses all of the above methods to create a cross-browser compatible offline database. It can also sync with an online database as an added feature.

Hope this helps, feel free to leave a comment if you want a bit more info.

Answer (score -4):

Use cookies there is a plugin for jquery cookies, really handy :) you could try that maybe?

Or just install mysql with php and store it, or only php and write a json file, or txt files :)

But I wonder why you don't have php ability, even if you work localhost you could easily setup xampp with apache mysql and php for example.

Comment: The cookie storage limit is too restrictive for this to be a solution

Comment: For only storing "name and a phone number" why would this not be a good solution? Why would the "storage limit" be "too restrictive"? (just asking).

Comment: The OP is unclear, however can be interpreted as requiring multiple separate records to be stored per client (and there's no indication that this would have any specific limit). As the cookie limit per domain for modern browsers is typically 50, cookies would only allow a maximum of 50 records to be stored, and the solution would be clumsy. The question suggests a requirement for a storage method that can be considered more of a 'local data store'.